# How could I update the database using LINQ

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, linq

So, I have a problem, connected with updating database, containing my own entities

```
class WordEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string word { get; set; }
    public int frequency { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return word;
    }
}
```

I have already filled it with words from some txt file and counted the number of their appearence (for each word).
Now I need to add more words from another txt file and count the number of their appearence as well. The problem is to write LINQ statement, which have to update existing words (their frequencies) and to add more new words.
I used this, but EF throws an exception, connected with `.Concat`

```
var t = context.Words
         `.Concat`(tempList)
         .GroupBy(w => w.word)
         .Select(w => new WordEntity() {word = w.Key, frequency = w.Sum(z => z.frequency)});
```

`templist` is a `List<WordEntity>` of new words from new txt file.
Please help.

Comment: What's the exception? I imagine it's because you're trying to join a database table with an in-memory list, which obviously doesn't make sense nor it's possible

Comment: the exception is: Exception in UpdateLibrary(): Processing of the LINQ expression 'DbSet<WordEntity>
    .Concat(__p_0)' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.

Comment: you are right, but I have no idea how to solve it correctly.

Comment: From what I can see, you seem to want to get the entire `Words` table. If that's the case, the solution is as simple as `context.Words.AsEnumerable().Contact(tempList)....`

Comment: to my regret, it hasn't helped, the problem remains. I also need to update my table

Comment: could you define precisely context.Words? its also a `List<WordEntity>` ?

Comment: @EduardBalakh, which database do you use? Also it is acceptable for you to use third party EF Core extensions? EF Core is not designed for performance in such cases, so it needs support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's different strategies you could use, but in essence you need to check, for each word in the new file, whether the word is already in the database. If it isn't, you need to add one (with frequency 1). Otherwise, you need to increase the frequency of the existing word. One solution is something like this:

```
using var context = new MyContext();
foreach (var word in ReadWordsFromFile(filename))
{
    var existingWord = await context.Words.SingleOrDefaultAsync(w => w.Word == word);
    if (existingWord is null)
    {
        context.Add(new WordEntity { Word = word, Frequency = 1 });
    }
    else
    {
        existingWord.Frequency++;
    }
}
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

You can also (as you were doing) try to read all entities from the database at once and do the whole operation in memory:

```
var existingWords = await context.Words.ToDictionaryAsync(w => w.Word);

foreach (var word in ReadWordsFromFile(filename))
{
    if (existingWords.ContainsKey(word))
        existingWords[word].Frequency++;
    else
    {
        var wordEntity = new WordEntity { Word = word, Frequency = 1 };
        context.Add(wordEntity);
        existingWords[word] = wordEntity;
    }
}
```

This may be faster (as everything is done in memory) but could become problematic as the database grows, as you will need more and more memory to fetch all data from the database. The first solution will only fetch the words from the database that are actually required.

Answer (score 0):

Although Jeroen's answer will work, it is not very efficient. Suppose the word "The" appears 10.000 times in the file, then he will fetch the frequency 10.000 times from the database and add +1

Wouldn't it be better to first check that this word appears 10.000 times, and then add or update the frequency +1000.

You could do this with the following:

```
IEnumerable<string> newWords = ReadWordsFromFile(...)
var newWordFrequencies = newWords.GroupBy(word => word,

    // parameter resultSelector: from every key (which is a word, and all occurences
    // of this word, make one new:
    (key, wordsEqualToThisKey) => new
    {
        Word = key,
        Count = wordsEqualToThisKey.Count(),
    });

    foreach (var newWord in newWordFrequencies)
    {
         // fetch the frequency from the database. if it exists: add count
         var fetchedExistingWord = dbContext.Words
             .Where(existingWord => existingWord.Word == newWord)
             .FirstOrDefault();
         if (fetchedExistingWord != null)
         {
              fetchedExistingWord.Frequency += newWord.Count;
         }
         else
         {
             // new Word is not in the database yet; add it
             dbContext.Words.Add(new WordEntity
             {
                  Word = newWord.Word,
                  Frequency = newWord.Count,
             });
         }
    }
```